# the output is the same despite values been diffrent

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    printf("enter the value ");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    if(ch>=65&&ch<=90)
    {
        printf("the character entered is uppercase\n");
    }
    if(ch>=97 && ch<=122)
    {
        printf("the character entered is lowercase\n");
    }
    if(ch>=48 && ch<=57)
    {
        printf("the character entered is numerical\n");
    }
    if((ch>=0 && ch<48)||(ch>57 && ch<65)||(ch>90 && ch<97)||(ch>123 && ch<128))
    {
        printf("the character is a special symbol\n");
    }
return 0;    
}
```

the ouptut always comes out to be
"the character entered is numerical"
no matter what value i put in
please tell what is wrong with the code

Comment: You should not use such magic numbers. If you want to use `'A'`, then just write `'A'` instead of `65`. It only makes code hard to read any easy to introduce errors.

Comment: You should replace your 4 `if` statements with a sequence of `if () } else if () {}...`. That will avoid typing that huge condition for the last `if`. That condition is also wrong as value `57` will be accepted for numerical check as well as the special symbol check

Comment: For me, your code works fine unless I enter `'9'`.

Comment: yeah that 57 part you said that was an error made by me ill correct that but apart from that i cant figure out what is wrong like i just ran the code and put the value "98" the output was  the value is numerical and special symbol

Comment: enter the value 98
the character entered is numerical
the character is a special symbol

Comment: this was the output

Comment: When you give the input `98<enter>` your program only reads the `9`

Comment: how can i fix that

Comment: and still 9 does not satisfy eithers conditions so how can the compiler say it is both num and special

Comment: You can read a full sring instead of a character. Use `fget` instead of `scanf("%c",&ch);` But then it will be a completely different program....

Comment: If you type "98", `scanf()` will read the first character '9' (ASCII 57) only and then you get crrectly 'numerical' + 'special' because of the bug in the last condition

Comment: @akshat.1010 The reason it says bot is that your last if-statement is wrong. `ch>=57` --> `ch>57` But as Gerhardh said above: Use of `else if` would simplify your program

Comment: i corrected the ch>57 part you just said and yes you are right if else would simplify

Comment: See https://ideone.com/CXrl3j

Comment: now the code is running

Comment: instead of char i declared it an integer

Comment: why not use the `ctype.h` functions such as `isalnum`, `isalpha` etc?

Comment: i m new,never heard of it , i'll definitely look that up

Comment: "and still 9 does not satisfy eithers conditions so how can the compiler say it is both num and special" Character `'9'`has value 57 which is checked in both `if` conditions as I mentioned above. Besides that, one incorrect character isn't really "no matter what value I provide"